# Restricting user to one open tab in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, browser, jquery-cookie

I had a requirement to restrict my web site's users to just one open tab in the browser. I am aware that this is not the best thing to do in terms of general user experience guidelines but its an internal application that doesn't play well with such a scenario so had to do it.

Following is what I came up with

```js
function IsNewTab() {
  return $.cookie('TabOpen');
}

$(function() {
  if (!IsNewTab()) {
    $.cookie('TabOpen', "YES", {
      path: '/'
    });
    $(window).unload(function() {
      $.removeCookie('TabOpen', {
        path: '/'
      });
    });
  } else {
    alert('already some tab open')
      //OR
      //window.close()
  }
});
```

I'd like opinions on the above. Are there any loopholes (keeping in mind that the target audience isn't too technical and probably won't go hacking around with the browser console). Are there any possible improvements that can be made ?

Comment: If you need restrictions like that, build a desktop app. The web is free. Live with it.

Comment: @GolezTrol Totally agree, except for the fact that I mentioned in my post that this is an internal application

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: you are talking about browser tab or some jquery library with html tags

Comment: @EhsanSajjad browser tabs